# ubuntu 20.04 kernel downgrade from 10.15 to 10.13 fails on update-grub

Tags: 20.04, grub2, kernel

Team,
I need to downgrade my kernel and i am stuck at this step. any hints? please observe my system details and what all i did and stuck at `sudo: upgrade-grub: command not found`

I want to have `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-52-generic`

```
user@user-DT:~$ cat /usr/sbin/update-grub
#!/bin/sh
set -e
exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"

user@user-DT:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

user@user-DT:~$ uname -a
Linux user-DT 5.15.0-72-generic #79~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 22:12:07 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

user@user-DT:~$ sudo grep 'menuentry \|submenu ' /boot/grub/grub.cfg | cut -f2 -d "'"
Ubuntu
Advanced options for Ubuntu
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-72-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-72-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-46-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-46-generic (recovery mode)
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-52-generic
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-52-generic (recovery mode)
UEFI Firmware Settings

user@user-DT:~$ cat /etc/default/grub | grep DEFA
GRUB_DEFAULT='Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.13.0-52-generic'
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

```
user@user-DT:~$ sudo upgrade-grub
sudo: upgrade-grub: command not found
```

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?   A fully upgraded Ubuntu 20.04 system will not report itself as 20.04.5 (and [hasn't for some time](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/)), and 5.13 is not a *supported* kernel for 20.04 (*GA remains 5.4 for the life of the product, and 5.15 is now the only supported HWE kernel*).  Your provided details resemble a Ubuntu based system more than a Ubuntu 20.04 system, and only official Ubuntu is on-topic here (refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: FYI:   I think you wanted to use `update-grub` thus the *command not found* message  (you use `grub-install` to upgrade (ie. install a newer version) it, and `update-grub` to update the existing grub configuration; ie. no version change of grub)

Comment: that was right. thanks. set it as answer.